# Selenium web driver with Cassandra service

Tags: cassandra-2.0

How to connect the Cassandra service with the selenium webdriver ? so that we can easily validate the required data in the DB.

Comment: You cannot connect the Cassandra service with the selenium webdriver. Tell us at least what programing language you are using.

Comment: Please also check this stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not 'testing tool'.
Selenium is tool\library for browser automation, therefore you cannot connect to database using selenium. 
You can connect to database using other libraries, but which library and how to do it is dependent of programing language that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mackowski